# How to add href height and width in code behind in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

im reading datas from xml.

```
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/multipleimage.xml"));
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("Image");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            HtmlAnchor a1 = new HtmlAnchor(); 
            Image imagesource = new Image();                
            string path = "Uploads/";
            string imageurl = path + node.SelectSingleNode("Imagepath").InnerText;
            imagesource.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingLeft, "7px");
            imagesource.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingRight, "5px");
            imagesource.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingTop, "5px");
            imagesource.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingBottom, "5px");
            imagesource.ImageUrl = imageurl;
            imagesource.Height = 90;
            imagesource.Width = 90;
            string imagetitle =  node.SelectSingleNode("imagetitle").InnerText;
            a1.Attributes.Add("href", imageurl);
            a1.Attributes.Add("rel", "lightbox[roadtrip]");                
            a1.Attributes.Add("title", imagetitle);
            a1.Controls.Add(imagesource);
            Div1.Controls.Add(a1); 
        }
    }
```

so im binding the controls in codebehind.i'm using lightbox effect also in code behind . everything is working fine.but can i set height and widht for the href from code behind?

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS to style your elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
HtmlAnchor a1 = new HtmlAnchor();
 a1.Style.Add("height", "120px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Href is an attribute of an anchor tag (`<a />`) and refers to the location the hyperlink will direct the browser to.

In general I would try to set classes and/or id's in the code behind and set style through css. This way you can change the style without recompiling:

```
a1.Attributes.Add("class", "my-class");
```

And in css:

```
.my-class
{
   width:100px;
   height:10px;
}
```

or for the image:

```
.my-class img
{
   width:100px;
   height:10px;
}
```

However lightbox may be updating these values. I would use a tool such as firebug (or the built in inspection tools - try pressing F12) to see what style is actually being added to the image elements.

Comment: particularily i want to change the height and width of the href image